# How can I compute the sum of the primes (with powers) that occur in the factorization of an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For example, $40=2^3\cdot 5$, so the sum $S(40)=2^3+5=13$. Also, $200=2^3\cdot 5^2$, so $S(200)=2^3+5^2=8+25=33$.
For a fixed $n$, I'd like to find some properties about $S(n)$. But I could find nothing through google; instead, a lot of people have considered the sum of prime factor without powers.

Comment: it is not multiplicative, so no pretty way to calculate it. Properties, not sure.

Comment: It sats $s(ab) = s(a) + s(b)$ for $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

Comment: @EnjoysMath, in that case something can be done, and, say, $e^s$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Very interesting problem. Who did you come up with this?

Comment: @WillJagy actually,what do you mean by "multiplicative"? I really could not understand it well.

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE ha, I thought about it because i could not fall asleep a few days ago. And found it a interesting problem.

Comment: @EnjoysMath i've noticed that. thank you all the same.

Comment: So you want to find the sum of factors raised to max power?

Comment: @shauryagupta yea, but I've given up since it's hopeless. see refs from Landau's function.

Answer (score 4):

$$ N = p q $$
$$S(N) = p + q$$

If you are given $S(N)$ and $N$ you can solve for $p$ and $q$. So the ability to compute $S(N)$ would allow you to factor semi-primes. So while you might find some properties, don't expect any kind of algorithm.

[Some references and properties for the sequence.](http://oeis.org/search?q=2,%203,%204,%205,%205,%207,%208,%209,%207,%2011,%207,%2013,%209,%208,%2016,%2017,%2011&sort=&language=english&go=Search)